# Starting value problem

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a system of non-linear ODEs but I get the error message:

> Cannot find starting value for the variable `f'`

This is the code:

```
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {h'[t] == -2 f[t], 
     f''[t] == -(g[t])^2 + (f[t])^2 + f'[t] h[t], 
     g''[t] == 2 f[t] g[t] + h[t] g'[t], 
     p'[t] == 2 f[t] h[t] - 2 f'[t], 
     f[0] == h[0] == p[0] == 0, g[0] == 1, 
     f[Infinity] == 0, g[Infinity] == 0}, 
    {f, h, g, p}, {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

Please I need your help.

Comment: Are you not missing some initial conditions like that of first derivatives of f and g?

Comment: No ... These are the boundary conditions I have ... I have the exact numerical solution in my course textbook, but I am required to solve these equations numerically and compare the results

Comment: @Subho95 No the OP does not miss it. Even if yes, I tried to change the conditions for usual ones, say placing `f'[0]==0` instead of the used `f[Infinity] == 0`. The outcome is invariable. @Muhammad, what system/version do you use? If I put the both conditions to `f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == 0` everything starts working.

Comment: @Subho95 In the book, it is written that: To solve these equations numerically, you should start with correct guess values of f' and g' that makes f and g zero at infinity.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch I am using Mathematica 11.3 on win7 x64

Comment: I don't know how to guess values for f' and g' in order to get f and g equal zero at infinity. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED:5.5.2018**

This boundary conditions: `f'[0] == 510/1000, g'[0] == -609/1000`, I'm searched by brute-force and help with **Maple 2018**.

```
sol2 = With[{inf = 47}, 
NDSolve[{h'[t] == -2*f[t], 
f''[t] == -(g[t])^2 + (f[t])^2 + f'[t]*h[t], 
g''[t] == 2*f[t]*g[t] + h[t]*g'[t], 
p'[t] == 2 f[t]*h[t] - 2 f'[t], f[0] == h[0] == p[0] == 0, 
g[0] == 1, f[inf] == 0, g[inf] == 0}, {f, h, g, p}, {t, 0, inf}, 
Method -> {"BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting", 
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == h[0] == p[0] == 0, 
g[0] == 1, f'[0] == 510/1000, g'[0] == -609/1000}}}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxSteps -> Infinity]];

Plot[Evaluate[{f[t], h[t], g[t], p[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, 47}, 
PlotLegends -> {"f[t]", "h[t]", "g[t]", "p[t]"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Check initial and boundary conditions at:  `t = 0`

```
{f[t], h[t], g[t], p[t]} /. sol /. t -> 0
(* {{0.*10^-25, 0.*10^-30, 1.0000000000000000000, 0.*10^-25}} *)
```

at: `t = 47`

```
{f[t], h[t], g[t], p[t]} /. sol /. t -> 47
(* {{7.5261038817*10^-11, 0.00014222313818378259662, -1.53486450848720*10^-10,-1.0043080818308*10^-8}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but only for inf = 6, and the problem is that I am required to compare my results with another solution that has numeric values at inf greater than 10. How can I work with inf = 15 for example?

Comment: Can you help please? @Mariusz Iwaniuk

Comment: @Muhammad.I edited my Answer.